# Calling a Web Service from PHP

Tags: php, drupal, web-services

How can i call a web service from php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `curl` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Assuming you are using a GET request to connect to a RESTful API:

```
$url = "http://the-api-you-want/?the-args=your-args&another-arg=another-arg"; 
$ch = curl_init(); // start CURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set your URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // get the response as a variable
$json = curl_exec($ch); // connect and get your JSON response 
curl_close($ch);
```

You can then use PHP's `json_decode` on the response if that is what you want to do.

Another option would be using Drupal's `drupal_http_request` function http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_http_request/6

Comment: Can u explain little bit more. I am new to CURL and i want to use json for data transfer

Comment: Do you mean you are expecting to receive a JSON response, or you want to send JSON in your query?

Comment: I have a built in web service that contain all database functionality
I want to use json for both sending and receving data to and from from the web service

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend you to be more specific in your Question. Wich Type of Web Service do you mean?

If you are using Rest Webservices, i can recommend Zend_Rest_Client, that comes with the Zend Framework. I think the Zend Framework also provides Stuff for SOAP Services.

Answer (score 0):

Use curl or the Zend_Http_Client library from Zend Framework (You don't need the entire Zend Framework to use the library). If the service you are calling is sending a JSON response, then you'll have to parse it in PHP using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).