# how to use a web service in php

Tags: php, web-services

I have a web service link to fetch some data from a site.the return data is in XML format.
have can i use this URL with PHP ? should i use cURL ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a Web Service from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707802/calling-a-web-service-from-php)

Comment: How do you mean? you get XML from a webservice and you want to parse this xml to data? or do you want to know how to implements webservices in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest way is use [cUrl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for fetching data from webservice and parsing response XML with [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [SAX](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) parser

Answer (score 1):

Use can use either SOAP or REST architecture for consuming web services in PHP.